# Proving a subset of the natural numbers has a minimal element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Given $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}, A \neq \emptyset$, prove that A has a minimum element.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please try to phrase questions a little more politely, rather than as commands :) It helps to keep things friendly if you say "I've tried to solve this problem by [...] but then I got stuck. Can anyone give me a hint?" instead of "Do this." (I've edited it in this direction. If you can show any attempt that's very helpful.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Use induction. Assume that $A$ has no least element, and show it must be empty, arriving at a contradiction.